# About the member "i_count" of structure "inode"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

"i_count" of structure "inode" is the reference to "inode".
When a process open a file and reads it, the value of "i_count" is 1.
When another process open the same file and reads it, **the value of "i_count" is still 1, not 2**.

Then what does the "i_count" of structure "inode" really mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i_count` is increased by code that is about to do something to the inode and needs to prevent it from being freed from the cache.
(See the [callers of `ihold()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=ihold).)

This additional reference is held only for a short time during such operations, so it is unlikely that you actually observe it.

Comment: thanks. Additional question, when we **"unlink"** the file, but the **"i_count"** is 1 (for example, the file has been opened by a process), does it not really remove the file from the disk?

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 0):

i_count is a kernel struct, represent how many function is using this "stuct inode".

It has no relationship with anything in user space.

I am a newbie in kernel, that's my understand.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).